# words around "or"

Tags: prepositions

I read the following sentence in a paper. I wonder if I can remove the second *by* and why.

> The refinement is done *by* moving the boundaries of the superpixels, or
>   equivalently, *by* exchanging pixels between neighboring superpixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can the first preposition *by* govern two objects, *moving* and *exchanging*? Of course. Some call this a species of *zeugma*. The problem is a stylistic one of sending your readers down a garden path, i.e., providing the opportunity to make an incorrect parse, if only temporarily. You have a comma after *equivalently*, a common use after any introductory adverb. But a comma also separates independent clauses, and the gerund clause *exchanging pixels* could make a fine subject, possibly leading your readers to expect a sentence like

> The refinement is done by moving the boundaries of the superpixels, or equivalently, exchanging pixels between neighboring superpixels will do the trick.

Of course, any such readers will realize their error when they reach the end of the sentence after the final prepositional phrase. They will then go back and reparse the sentence to recognize the prepositional phrase with a compound object.

But this is bad manners as well as bad style. Leave in the second *by* as a courtesy to your readers.

Comment: So, both are right. The original one (i.e., with the second *by*) is better for reader?

Comment: Yes, both are grammatical and mean the same thing. It's just that without repeating *by*, the sentence is harder to parse. Was it clear in the explanation why that would be?

Comment: :) your explanation is very professional. I was just asking for sure. Thanks very much. :)

Comment: @aban. No, both aren't 'right'. There is a widespread misconception that if something is grammatical, it's automatically acceptable. Sometimes, perfectly grammatical sentences are needlessly ambiguous (which is very serious) or needlessly difficult to parse (as here). I'd knock a mark off here (in an English essay) for wilfully and nonsensically omitting a small word that makes quite a difference to ease of reading (for the reason deadrat gives).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Writing clear English is difficult. (Check out the small edit I made to the answer to eliminate my own bit of ambiguity.) The OP is not willful because he's having trouble coping with the unfamiliar; the OP is not nonsensical because he hasn't had enough practice to separate sense from nonsense.

Comment: I see you fail to take account of the 'in an English essay' qualification. Worrying, for someone who has 35k rep here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My comment has nothing to do with English essays (for which knocking off a mark would be fitting in this case) and everything to do with ascribing moral and intellectual failure to low-rep users grappling with the task of producing clear English prose. I think this attitude is a problem. And if you're really worrying about my observation, then you've got two.

Comment: I didn't say that the OP was either wilful or nonsensical. I said that if I had to mark an essay by someone (the context is a published paper on an obviously academic subject, where writing advice is doubtless available) who should know better,  I would down-mark for the 'bad manners as well as bad style' you yourself mention. You are the one implying that I'm speaking about a user here rather than a hypothetical publishing author. And I'm rather tired of your petty attitude.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth As Philip Marlowe said when he got a complaint about his manner, "Yeah, I've had complaints about it, but it keeps getting worse." Your comment makes no mention of published papers, "obviously" academic subjects, or authors who should know better. Just of marking an English essay, an assignment that it's no stretch to consider that the OP might be given. I'm not implying that your original comment is applicable to the OP; I'm stating it outright. If that's not what you meant, then so be it, but please don't pretend I'm out of line.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can remove the second **by** as **equivalently** is by itself enough  to convey the sense of by.

Comment: Is it better to keep 'equivalently' and the comma?

Comment: *The* answer? Says who? Matters of style generally don't have definitive answers. How does two words (*along with*) as opposed to one (*by*) "lighten" text? *Through* doesn't indicate "opposition", and any wording to emphasize "contrast" changes the meaning of the sentence, if only slightly. Most style guides would not advise a comma after *superpixels* and before *or* to avoid the very garden path I mentioned.

Comment: Disregarding opportunities to always better ourselves undermines ultimately the capacity to grow. 'Style' is a very important component in writing, and I wouldn't underestimate the benefits of its misconstrued futility.  Using metaphoric verbs to enchant the monotony of a text is perhaps unnecessary, be as it may, repetitions are not a matter of style. Finding a synonym, is where the passion for writing begins.